# smsAuthentication XML API DOCUSIGN

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to send an sms text of an accesscode defined in the API send doc call to a specified phone number? The tag is smsAuthentication in signers recipient section.

```
"</document>" +
"</documents>" +
"<recipients>" +
"<signers>" +
"<signer>" +
"<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
"<email>joe@email.com</email>" +
"<accessCode>1234</accessCode>" +
  "<addAccessCodeToEmail>true</addAccessCodeToEmail>" +
  "<smsAuthentication>" +
      "<senderProvidednumbers>5555555555</senderProvidednumbers>" +
  "</smsAuthentication>" +
```

Answer (score 2):

When using SMS via REST with XML you'll need a couple more parameters:

```
"<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
"<email>joe@email.com</email>" +
"<requireIdLookup>true</requireIdLookup> +
"<idCheckConfigurationName>SMS Auth $</idCheckConfigurationName>" +
"<smsAuthentication>" +
    "<senderProvidednumbers>5555555555</senderProvidednumbers>" +
"</smsAuthentication>" +
```

The requireIdLookup says that an extended authentication is required while idCheckConfigurationName specifies what security configuration should be used.  The numbers you list will be displayed to the signer so they can choose which one to use at the time of signing.

Comment: This worked but the phone numbers are not listed on the page to select then send the code. How do i make the numbers list on the page? –

Comment: There is/was an issue where the SMS numbers weren't populated for calls using the simple "templateId" mode.  If you use Composite Templates instead it will work.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign has many different ways to authenticate signers. You seem to be mixing the `AccessCode` and `SMS Authentication` methods. They are different. Use one or the other:

**AccessCode** -- You (the sender) supply an Access Code for 2 Factor Authentication (2FA) of the signer (Email and the Access Code). You should send the Access Code to the signer using some transmission method that is NOT email. A common example is to use a "pre-shared secret" such as the last 4 digits of the signer's Social Security number (US) or other identifier.

You should never use the DocuSign envelope option "addAccessCodeToEmail" since it turns a 2FA process back into a single factor authentication process (all of the needed information would be in the email).

See the [DocuSign Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm).

**SMS Authentication** This is a different 2FA process for authenticating signers. In this scenario, the DocuSign platform generates a 5 digit code and then sends it via SMS to the signer during the signing ceremony. You can customize the SMS message via the DocuSign "Branding" settings. (Changing the Branding for a DocuSign account is not available for all account types.)

If you want to generate your own "AccessCode" and then send it via SMS, then you will need to send it yourself. There are many SMS gateways available. Note that you will not know *when* to send the code since the best time to send the code is during the signing ceremony. Your SMS would show up at a different time and would not provide a good User Experience.

I recommend the SMS Authentication as provided by DocuSign.

Comment: How would the smsauthentication look in the xml section of the api call? I agree, i want ti use the Docusign SMS feature for sure.

Comment: This worked but the phone numbers are not listed on the page to select then send the code. How do i make the numbers list on the page?